# Clarification of List<'T> definition syntax

Tags: f#

While reading the source code of F#, I found the [definition](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/fsharp4/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L3480)  of the `List<'T>` type, which looks like this:

```
type List<'T> = 
       | ([])  :                  'T list
       | (::)  : Head: 'T * Tail: 'T list -> 'T list
```

Could someone, please, explain the above syntax? The compiler warns that 'This construct is deprecated: it is only for use in the F# library'. Is the syntax just an old way to define discriminated unions? If so, why does `Tail` has the type of `'T list -> 'T list` instead of just `'T list`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what this means is the following:

```
type List<'T> = 
       | ([])  :                  'T list
       | (::)  : (Head: 'T * Tail: 'T list) -> 'T list
```

That is to say, `(::)` is a function that, given an ordered pair `'T * 'T list` generates a `'T list`.

The deprecated construct is giving type annotations to the discriminated union constructors. You never needed to do that, in any version of F#, as far as I know. I don't know why they had to do that in the F# library.

Comment: Would that also be equivalent to

 "type MyList<'T> = 
       | ([]) of                   'T list
       | (::)  of Head: 'T * Tail: 'T list"

?

Comment: Yes, it is, in every respect. It's just that in principle, (::) is a function.

Comment: OK, thank you. I made a test type like this: 

"type Test =
      | Case1 : int -> Test
      | Case2 : string -> Test".

Although the deprecation warning is still there, the type works as expected. 'let test1 = Case1 (5)', 'let test2 = Case2 ("test")'. I guess you are right - the warning means that we should use "Case1 of int" instead of "Case1 : int -> Test". Thanks once again.

Comment: (::) is function that can construct a list but also a pattern that can be used during pattern matching